# git - how do I switch my app to use code from a different remote origin (not just a URL change, has different git history)

Tags: git

I had some intractable git-history related issues in my current (Rails) code repo, whose remote origin on Github is "V1.git"

Thanks to help in another SO thread, I made an all-new repo with the issues fixed, and pushed the master branch of the new (fixed) repo to a new Github repo named "V2.git". FWIW, the files at the "HEAD" of both V1 and V2 are the same, but, if it matters, the most recent commit IDs are not the same and V2 also has a lot more git history.

How can I force-overwrite V2 from Github to my development folder MYAPP, while leaving all untracked files alone?

I'm guessing I probably:

- in MYAPP, delete the current remote "origin" (points to V1)
- and also probably delete the .git folder,
- then simply clone V2 into the existing MYAPP folder where it will leave untracked file alone?

Or perhaps should I:

- in MYAPP, delete the current remote "origin" (points to V1)
- and delete the .git folder
- then add the new remote "origin" (points to V2)
- then do `git init`
- then something like `git pull origin master` ?

Or perhaps it is as simple as adding "origin" to point to V2, then doing some sort of forced git-pull?

Comment: Note that in any Git repository, the hash ID *is* the commit. The history is the *set of commits* in the repository, as found by starting at the latest commit(s), as found by branch and tag names, and working backwards: each (immutable) commit records the raw hash ID of its predecessors. Hence, the *last* commit determines the *entire history of all commits*, by definition. You simply choose which *last* commit(s) you want. (In any case, ErikMD's answer seems fine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The step `delete the .git folder` seems unnecessary.

But you'll probably want to **backup your entire MYAPP folder first**, as better safe than sorry.

Then, a straightforward procedure would be:

```
git checkout master

git remote remove origin

git remote add origin git@github.com:YourLogin/V2.git  # with the proper URL

git fetch origin

git reset --soft origin/master
# ↑ may suffice for your use case

# OR git reset --hard origin/master
# ↑ risk: overwriting unsaved changes or files untracked in V1 but tracked in V2

git branch -u origin/master
# ↑ optional: allows one to use `git push` and `git pull` without any argument
```

Then inspect the new repository state, with `git status` or [`gitk`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk).

Comment: Pretty sure you want `git reset --soft` actually

Comment: Also `git remote set-url` should work rather than deleting the remote entirely.

Comment: @o11c: I was aware of `git remote set-url` but it think it is only appropriate when the same remote is moved from one host to another host (a lightweight move then), while the OP specifically mentions the two remotes are strongly different, so if ever the OP runs `git remote set-url`, there is the risk that several obsolete tracking branches remain from `V1`…

Comment: plus 1 for "backup" - whats the verdict on soft vs hard reset?

Comment: according to the question sentence `the files at the "HEAD" of both V1 and V2 are the same`, `git reset --hard` and `git reset --soft` should give the same outcome, so as suggested by @o11c, you may want to stick to the softer version; then `git diff` afterwards should print nothing or so (but in a more general situation, it's not specially "dangerous" **at least w.r.t. tracked changes** to do `git reset --hard`, which means move HEAD **and** overwrite the working directory accordingly: thanks to `git reflog` it's always possibility to recover a content **that had been tracked** in a commit).

Comment: used the soft resets. worked great, thank you all!